# Should we close this question asking about unusual instruments?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

In my opinion, this question is off-topic: [Instruments that challenge your ear](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/22257/instruments-that-challenge-your-ear)

It asks for a list of unusual instruments. As a list question, it doesn't have a single answer and is effectively a shopping cart question. Do you agree, or am I being too harsh?

If we agree the question is off-topic, someone should close it. It's at 4 close votes. I think it's especially important the question is closed because it's currently in the hot questions list, meaning that we're potentially being represented by an off-topic question.

Comment: The question has been closed now.

Comment: As there were already 4 votes I could cast a non-mod vote :-)

I 100% agree with this being closed - it was only ever going to generate a subjective list of instruments that folks may or may not agree are challenging, based on their experience

Comment: I don't disagree, but the question was fun while it lasted.

Comment: The question was reopened. Why? I still believe it should be closed and hope more people close it a second time.

Comment: Maybe it's interesting

Answer (score 3):

When is something I play good?  When it sounds good.  It doesn't matter what rules of harmony may have been broken, as long as it sounds good.

When is a question good?  When it gets a lot of responses and upvotes and interesting answers.  Yep, it breaks the SE rules.  So what?  The question was closed but reopened due to popular demand.

"We tried to hang him Sheriff, but the rope broke." "I guess we have to let the rascal live."

Comment: But - but the rules! *sobs uncontrollably*

Comment: In all seriousness, you're probably right. It's not worth falling on my sword over this, and whether it's an ok question or not, it's not going to bring down all of M&MP.SE.

Comment: This is what I am saying!!  The only thing I disagree with is that the SE rules are broken, but maybe I am missing something.  SE is about crowd-sourcing.  If the crowd accepts the question, then it is on-topic, period.